# Different classes that might be passed to constructor

Tags: c++, stl

The constructor of my class can have two different classes passed to it. But there's no way I can know ahead of time what type it will be so I can declare its type as a data member to initialize it. How can I know which kind of object was passed to my constructor. Preferably I would like this to be done **without** Boost.

I am passing in an iterator. It can either be a const iterator (`v.cbegin()`) or non-const (`v.begin()`):

```
struct iterator
{
    iterator(IteratorType it)
        : m_it(it)
    { }
IteratorType m_it;
};
```

Here's how I'm calling the constructor:

```
iterator X::begin()       { return iterator(x.begin()); }
iterator X::begin() const { return iterator(x.cbegin()); }
```

Comment: If you don't know what type you're going to get, what are you going to be able to do with that data?

Comment: Could you use templates?  (Assuming that both classes have a compatible interface.)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth They both have the same member functions.

Comment: @cdhowie Yes you can.

Comment: @user3577210: Any reason you can't define a common abstract base class for them?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth They are standard builtin classes.

Comment: @user3577210 Can you provide more information in the question?

Comment: Then a template is your answer.  There is no need for Boost, as there is nothing that needs to be done other than declare a class template (based on the information you've provided).

Comment: If it can have two different classes passed to it, just write two overloads, which might delegate to a common ctor. No need to over-engineer it.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Sorry I meant without Boost.

Comment: Do you mean two different classes or two different types of classes, aka they have different interfaces? In the first case, use two overloads, in the second, use template-ctors with SFINAE on an additional template-argument or defualt function argument.

Comment: @Deduplicator They both have the same interface. `x.begin()` and `x.cbegin()` have the same interface but are different instantiations of the same template.

Comment: I realize that what you posted probably isn't real code, but your constructor is private.

Comment: @user3577210: So, please clarify why simply having two overloads does not cut it.

Comment: @Deduplicator How do two overloads solve the problem? I still won't know what type was passed in.

Comment: Why do you want to know? What depends on that? And of course you know what type was passed to your function, all arguments have a type.

Comment: @Deduplicator I want to know because `iterator` wants to use the object that was passed in. This means that I have to know the type before I initialize it through the constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not actually want to know what argument-types were passed to your ctor, because by then the class is already under construction, its type cast in stone.

What you want is to decide on which class to use based on the arguments, which needs earlier intervention.
Still, the solution is simple:

Use a factory-function and a template-class (There are many examples of this pattern in `<iterator>` and other parts of the standard library)

```
template<class It>
struct myiterator
{
    myiterator(It it) : m_it(it) { }
private:
    typename std::iterator_traits<It>::type m_it;
    // The above will choke if It is not an iterator
};

template<class... X> auto make_myiterator(X&&.. x)
-> myiterator<typename std::decay<X>::type>
// Only the first arguments type is passed on.
{
    using just_making_sure_it_is_an_iterator =
        std::iterator_traits<typename std::decay<X>::type>::type;
    return {std::forward<X>(x)...};
}
```

Comment: I would stick a `typedef std::iterator_traits<typename std::decay<X>::type>::type just_making_sure_it_is_an_iterator;` in there.

Comment: Oh, I meant stick it in the body.  What you have now, if someone passes a `std::string`, they get "no function matches those parameters" on the calling line, which is confusing.  If it's in the body they get `std::string` does not have member `value_type` on the line that says `just_making_sure_it_is_an_iterator`. (Personal opinion)

Comment: @MooingDuck: Ah, I overthought it. Sure, there's no need to use SFINAE there, and suffer the resulting complicated error-messages. (Though there are some places I could wish the committee had been more enthusiastic about SFINAE, look at the stream extraction/insertion template for temporary streams.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using templates as suggested in the comments:

```
template<typename It>
struct iterator
{
    iterator(It it) : m_it(it) { }
private:
    It m_it;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If your target is to determine which type you are holding in your class, by just holding a more "general" type, then you could do this:

Implement a common interface class of those two classes and use this type as your constructor argument & property. Inside your interface, set up a method contract, that returns your type (i.e. a string or enum value, etc). Then, implement this method to both classes, in different implementation.

```
public class Iterateable
{
  public:
    //Ctors/Dtors etc....

    //Pure virtual method.
    virtual string getType() = 0;


}

public class IteratorType1 : public Iterateable
{
 public:
    //Ctors/Dtors etc....

    string getType {return "IteratorType1";}
}

public class IteratorType2 : public Iterateable
{
  public:
    //Ctors/Dtors etc....

    string getType {return "IteratorType2";}
}

struct iterator
{
    iterator(Iterateable it)
        : m_it(it)
    { }
Iterateable m_it;
};
```

You can then hold objects of any type that implement the Iterateable interface.
Then, by calling getType() via the property you can determine the type, as the method implemented on the mostly derived class of the instance holded on the property will be invoked (this is a language feature called [late binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding)).